# NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter() error on Hosting Server

Tags: pdf-generation, html-to-pdf

I am using the following code to generate pdf file from html text.

```
var htmlToPdf = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter();
byte[] pdfBytes = htmlToPdf.GeneratePdf(finalString.ToString());
```

It works fine when I run it locally on my machine, but on the hosting server, I am seeing the following error randomly. Pdf gets generated sometimes but sometimes it throws the following error.

"Error. An error occurred while processing your request.
Cannot generate PDF: (exit code: 1)"

Has anyone experienced this and have a fix for it?

Comment: Try turning off [`Quiet`](http://www.nrecosite.com/doc/NReco.PdfGenerator/html/P_NReco_PdfGenerator_HtmlToPdfConverter_Quiet.htm) mode and binding an event listener to [`LogReceived`](http://www.nrecosite.com/doc/NReco.PdfGenerator/html/E_NReco_PdfGenerator_HtmlToPdfConverter_LogReceived.htm)